# Graph in asp.net using telerik and sql server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, telerik

In my asp.net application, I need to draw graph with respect to the data in sql server.
Where i suggested to use Telerik to complete the task. Following is the method which i used for this task

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.default.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employees]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <script>
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
           // data: SqlDataSource1
            transport: {
                read: {
                    DataSourceID:"SqlDataSource1"
                }
});
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: dataSource,
            series: [
              { field: "name" }
            ]
        });
        dataSource.read();
        </script>
</body>
```

I am unable to see any output from the above code. Is there any specific property to add the asp.net datasource control to the kendo.data.DataSource method. So that read the data from table and draw the graph.
Here my sql server table

```
name      Price
-----     -----
Peter       2
Andrew      6
Julie       4
Mary        5
Dave        3
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For the ASP.NET AJAX wrapper see this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/databinding/database/defaultcs.aspx and use RadHtmlChart.

what you are attempting to do is to put server data source into a client data source control, which is not going to work.

Option 2 is to expose a service that will return the data you need: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datasource/remote-data-binding.